# hasMany join in cakephp error

Tags: mysql, cakephp, join, has-many

I have a table `jobs` whose structure is similar to below :

```
id      desc
1       Job Description
```

And a table `job_categories` to save the categories of the jobs:

```
id   job_id   category_id
1    1        2
2    1        3
3    1        4
```

So to get the categories gor the job with id `1` , in `JobsController.php`, I wrote:

```
$similar_conditions['JobCategory.job_id'] = 1;
$similar_jobs = $this->Job->find('all',array('conditions' => $similar_conditions));
```

And my job model `Job.php` is:

```
class Job extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Job';
    var $belongsTo = array('Qualification');
    var $hasMany = array('JobCategory');   
}
```

But it is showing an error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'JobCategory.job_id' in 'where clause'`. The query it is generating is:

> SQL Query: SELECT `Job`.`id`, `Job`.`job_title`,
>   `Job`.`job_description`, `Job`.`job_skills`, `Job`.`contact_number`,
>   `Job`.`contact_email`, `Job`.`qualification_id`, `Job`.`experience`,
>   `Job`.`categories`, `Job`.`remarks`, `Job`.`support_image`,
>   `Job`.`freshers_apply`, `Job`.`added_on`, `Job`.`status`,
>   `Qualification`.`id`, `Qualification`.`name` FROM `cakead`.`jobs` AS
>   `Job` LEFT JOIN `cakead`.`qualifications` AS `Qualification` ON
>   (`Job`.`qualification_id` = `Qualification`.`id`) WHERE
>   `JobCategory`.`job_id` = 1

Why my table job_categories is not joining ?

Comment: please add code of job model

Comment: Added the codes @Moyed Ansari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Cakephp [Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Basic-Principles-of-CakePHP/CakePHP-Conventions.html)

> Foreign keys in hasMany, belongsTo or hasOne relationships are
>   recognized by default as the (singular) name of the related table
>   followed by _id. So if a Baker hasMany Cake, the cakes table will
>   refer to the bakers table via a baker_id foreign key. For a multiple
>   worded table like category_types, the foreign key would be
>   category_type_id.

try this

```
var $hasMany = array(
        'JobCategory' => array(
            'className' => 'JobCategories',
            'foreignKey' => 'job_id',
            'dependent' => true,
        )
    );
```

Comment: you are not following cake convention job_categories. it should be job_categories

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here `$similar_conditions['JobCategory.job_id'] = 1;`.
You cann't use ['JobCategory.job_id'] in your Job model.

Try this

```
$similar_jobs = $this->Job->find('all',array(
                        'contain' => array(
                                 'JobCategory' => array(
                                         'conditions' => array(
                                                           $similar_conditions
                                                         )
                                                   )
                                                 )
                                         )
                                      );
```

And add containable behavior to your AppModel